# Markov chain- recurrent and transient?

Tags: markov-chains

In this Markov chain, are all the states recurrent since you can return back to every state starting anywhere?
or are there any transient states?

> A Markov chain has transition probability matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix}
>   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>   0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 \\
>   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>   0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$$

[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.All states are recurrent.